# How to extract table for pdf using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdftotext, camelot-php-tools

I am trying to extract table data in a structured manner as a table using Java.  I've been using pdfbox and tabula for the past two years.  But the problem is that pdfbox returns all the data in pdf as a sorted or unsorted text and tabula sometimes detects the table which have perfect borders and failed to recogonize tables without borders.

Please help me with a solution to extract table from pdf in a structured format using **Java** other than using **pdfbox and tabula api**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The LEADTOOLS Java Forms Processing SDK can be used for extracting table information from structured forms. The recognition uses a template from a blank form with fields defined for extraction. For example, a [TableFormField](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/fp/tableformfield.html) class can be configured for different tables using the Rules property with the appropriate [TableRules](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/fp/tablerules.html) value. A Java sample can be found [here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12833-) and a free evaluation is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Java to extract tables from PDF, then I think this method is very suitable for you. Use the Spire.PDF for Java control to complete this operation.[Spire.PDF for Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-java.html) offers the **PdfTableExtractor.extractTable(int pageIndex)** method to detect and extract tables from a desired PDF page.
You can refer to the following Java code:

```
       //Loop through the pages in the PDF
       for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pdf.getPages().getCount(); pageIndex++) {
       
       //Extract tables from the current page into a PdfTable array
       PdfTable[] tableLists = extractor.extractTable(pageIndex);
```

Here is the complete article tutorial :[Extract Table Data from PDF Document in Java.](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.PDF-for-Java/Program-Guide/Table/Java-Extract-Table-Data-from-PDF-Document.html) I hope this answer is extremely helpful to you.